# received this error when running the flutter code : Error: No named parameter with the name 'body'

Tags: parameters, scaffold

I hope you are doing great. I am trying to centralize an image at the level of the body using flutter but I instead receive this error: Error: No named parameter with the name 'body'.
body: Center( .please what can I do to solve the issue?  it is that the scaffold doesn't recognize body as widget? I am still a beginner .
this is my code:
void main() {
runApp(MaterialApp(
home: Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
appBar: AppBar(
title: Center(
child: Text('i am rich'),
),
body: Center(
child: Image(
image: NetworkImage(
'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS8-IFMk0FedZHVr-O9tluME2jy9-DXTV3TXA&usqp=CAU'),
),
),
),
),
));
}

Comment: You are passing body to AppBar instead of the Scaffold, which is why it complains that AppBar does not support a body parameter